# Accessing data in a Pandas dataframe with one row

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I use Pandas dataframes to manipulate data and I usually visualise them as virtual spreadsheets, with rows and columns defining the positions of individual cells. I'm happy with the methods to slice and dice the dataframes but there seems to be some odd behaviour when the dataframe contains a single row. Basically, I want to select rows of data from a large parent dataframe that meet certain criteria and then pass those results as a daughter dataframe to a separate function for further processing. Sometimes there will only be a single record in the parent dataframe that meets the defined criteria and, therefore, the daughter dataframe will only contain a single row. Nevertheless, I still need to be able to access data in the daughter in the same way as for the parent database. To illustrate may point, consider the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
tempDF = pd.DataFrame({'group':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2],
                       'string':['a','b','c','d','a','b','c','d']})
print(tempDF)
```

Which looks like:

```
   group string
0      1      a
1      1      b
2      1      c
3      1      d
4      2      a
5      2      b
6      2      c
7      2      d
```

As an example, I can now select those rows where 'group' == 2 and 'string' == 'c', which yields just a single row. As expected, the length of dataframe is 1 and it's possible to print just a single cell using .ix() based on index values in the original dataframe:

```
tempDF2 = tempDF.loc[((tempDF['group']==2) & (tempDF['string']=='c')),['group','string']]
print(tempDF2)
print('Length of tempDF2 = ',tempDF2.index.size)
print(tempDF2.loc[6,['string']])
```

Output:

```
   group string
6      2      c
Length of tempDF2 =  1
string    c
```

However, if I select a single row using .loc, then the dataframe is printed in a transposed form and the length of the dataframe is now given as 2 (rather than 1). Clearly, it's no longer possible to select single cell values based on index of original parent dataframe:

```
tempDF3 = tempDF.loc[6,['group','string']]
print(tempDF3)
print('Length of tempDF3 = ',tempDF3.index.size)
```

Output:

```
group     2
string    c
Name: 7, dtype: object
Length of tempDF3 =  2
```

In my mind, both these methods are actually doing the same thing, namely selecting a single row of data. However, in the second example, the rows and columns are transposed making it impossible to extract data in an expected way.

Why should these 2 behaviours exist? What is the point of transposing a single row of a dataframe as a default behaviour? How can I make sure that a dataframe containing a single row isn't transposed when I pass it to another function?

Comment: would `tempDF.loc[6:6]` solve your issue?

Comment: I guess the second one is actually returning an ndarray instead

Comment: @MaxU - yes, that does also work. Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
tempDF3 = tempDF.loc[6,['group','string']]
```

The `6` in the first position of the `.loc` selection dictates that the return type will be a Series and hence your problem.  Instead use `[6]`:

```
tempDF3 = tempDF.loc[[6],['group','string']]
```

Comment: So I guess passing lists to .loc() is the rule to go by. Thanks so much for that – I could have been looking for hours to find such a subtle solution.

Comment: I just noticed passing list to loc is VERY slow. But passing slice ie .loc[6:6] is fast and works as needed

Comment: @AnatoliyOrlov that is interesting.  I'm going to mess around with that.  Thanks for telling me.